# how to make scroll to opened div

Tags: scroll

HTML:

```
<a class="targetLink" href="#">LINK1</a>
<div id="text1" style="display: none;">text1 div</div>

<a class="targetLink" href="#">LINK2</a>
<div id="text2" style="display: none;">text2 div</div>

<a class="targetLink" href="#">LINK3</a>
<div id="text3" style="display: none;">text3 div</div>
```

JS:

```
$("a.targetLink").toggle(function() {
    $(".open").slideUp(350);
    $(this).next("div").slideDown(350).addClass("open");
}, function() {
    $(this).next("div").slideUp(350).removeClass("open");
});
```

It works this way: when u press a link with class "targetLink" it opens a DIV below it. Now i need to modify js code to: when i click then link it scrolls to the beginning of that opened div. How can i achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use scrollTop on the element that you want to scroll to the top of. http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

example:

```
$(this).next("div").scrollTop(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need, and maybe more: [**My jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpressley1/fccCJ/59/). I'm not sure what you've got working so far, but this does what i think you're going for, without the need for additional jquery plugins, etc.

here's the JS(check the jsfiddle for html):

```
$(".pop").hide();
$(".targetLink").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var n = $(this).next();
    if(!$(n).hasClass('open')){ 
        $(".open").removeClass('open').slideUp(200);
        $(n).addClass('open').slideDown(200); 
    } 
});


$(".nav").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var dest=null;
    if(($($(this.hash)).offset().top) > ($(document).height()-$(window).height())){
        dest= $(document).height()-$(window).height();
    }else{
        dest=$($(this.hash)).offset().top;
    }
    $($(this.hash)).trigger("click");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 500, 'swing' );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this really great and simple jQuery plugin - https://github.com/Ashwell/jquery-scrollThis

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're asking for:

```
self.scrollToDiv = function scrollToDiv(element,minus){
    element = element.replace("link", "");
    if(minus==null){
        minus=0;
    }
    $('html,body').unbind().animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top+minus},'slow');
};
```